# Cannot Connect to internet in windows 7 (No Internet Connection)

Tags: windows-7

I have an airport express and Win 7 pro. My router is a Trendnet TEW-423PI G. The problem is everytime i try to connect it says it is unsuccessful and can't find ip address. I have tried everything. WPA2, WPA, WEP, Messing with the registry, Manually Inputting the ip address, Reinstalling drivers. I have two Macs that connect perfectly and are both running Snow Leopard that is why I am able to post this. ***What Should I do.*** ***I'm Going Crazy***

Comment: I've found that disabling the LLTD stuff and IPv6 (if not needed) in the network adapter's properties can help with some connectivity issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you double checked on the router if it has any security such as MAC filtering?

After this, I would double check that you have selected the right Encryption type (TKIP/AES).

Lastly, double check DHCP settings / as you said you did manual, make sure that the settings are correct.

I have seen your issue a few times when either one of the three above problems exist.. If you still have the problem, please say

Answer (score 0):

If Wil's answer didn't solve the problem, have a look at the following article:
[Trendnet TEW-423PI wireless PCI adapter](http://www.fixya.com/support/t2735761-trendnet_tew_423pi_wireless_pci_adater).

The article explains the steps to take to verify connecting to the wifi card.

If this does not work, and you wish to have more help, please add to your post the output you get from running the following commands in Command Prompt (cmd):

> ipconfig /all
>  ping
>   192.168.2.1
>  ping www.google.com

You might also add a comment below to notify me that this output is ready.

Answer (score 0):

When I got my new computer with Windows 7 last month, I had the same problem, and went through the same steps you did.  Here are two things that worked for me:

1. Make sure you have the Security Type option for authentication correct: change from No Authentication (Open) to Shared or vice versa.
2. Change the Homegroup name from whatever Windows assigned when you set up your connection to the network you assigned both your Macs.