# I have just reinstalled windows xp and I cant connect to the internet

Tags: windows, windows-xp, internet

I have just reinstalled windows xp on a HP a1268c and I can't connect to the internet. My Network card in device manager says it is functioning fine. However I can't connect to the internet at all. I have upgraded to sp2 with a disk I allready had. I have tried ipconfig and all I get in return is "Windos IP Configuration".

Answer (score 3):

If you don't get a report on it, then Windows is not detecting your adapter *as* a network adapter, or possibly you don't have any network protocols installed.  Open the Properties for "Local Network Connection" and make sure that Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) is installed and configured correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are many "Cannot Connect to the internet" questions with answers on this board.  You will need to employ general troubleshooting to fix your problem.  CarlF has a good point, but you will find that doing multiple tasks is required to get your problem fixed.  Here are some posts that may help:

[Single computer on network cannot connect to internet](https://superuser.com/questions/136138/single-computer-on-network-cannot-connect-to-internet)

[How do I solve an unidentified network issue? It can't connect to the Internet](https://superuser.com/questions/60054/windows-7-unidentified-network-problem-cannot-connect-to-the-internet)

[Internet connection fails on 1 machine, the other is OK](https://superuser.com/questions/180598/internet-connection-fails-on-1-machine-the-other-is-ok/180608#180608)

[Cannot Connect to internet in windows 7 (No Internet Connection)](https://superuser.com/questions/85467/cannot-connect-to-internet-in-windows-7-no-internet-connection)

[Unable to connect to network](https://superuser.com/questions/129287/unable-to-connect-to-network)

Perhaps running a general search on Superuser, "Cannot Connect to Network" will give you some hints.